# Assembly code generalization

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, optimization, x86

I encountered the following code in my computer architecture class:

```
void mystery( long A[], long B[], long n )
{
  long i;
  for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    B[i] = A[n-(i+1)];
  }
}
```

And my professor showed the corresponding assembly code GCC generates on an Ubuntu machine and he seems to be confused as well:

```
mystery:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movq    %rdi, -24(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -32(%rbp)
    movq    %rdx, -40(%rbp)
    movq    $0, -8(%rbp)
    jmp .L2
.L3:
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    leaq    0(,%rax,8), %rdx
    movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    addq    %rax, %rdx
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    notq    %rax
    movq    %rax, %rcx
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rax
    addq    %rcx, %rax
    leaq    0(,%rax,8), %rcx
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    addq    %rcx, %rax
    movq    (%rax), %rax
    movq    %rax, (%rdx)
    addq    $1, -8(%rbp)
.L2:
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    cmpq    -40(%rbp), %rax
    jl  .L3
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

But I can't understand why the compiler will generate this code. It appears the A, B, and n are pushed onto the stack but the stack pointer %rsp doesn't change its value. Also, -16(%rbp) also seems to be allocated but is never put in a value. Is there any reason GCC will behave this way?

Comment: It's using the red zone which is available without allocation. As to the particular layout, who knows. PS: also note this is unoptimized code, which in general may do silly things. Try using `-O2` so you will get more sensible output.

Comment: Much more sensible/readable output with `gcc -O2`: https://godbolt.org/g/pS3tu8

Comment: `A, B, n, i` are stored into local stack memory and constantly being read/updated because this is debug build, so the debugger can use the stack frame to show "watch" window with proper values in each variable. The optimized assembly doesn't do that and the "watch" window in debugger will be probably unable to track current values in variables. About layout and not using -16 ... well, it's not a task of compiler to produce nice minimal stack frame layout. Valid+working is its only aim. A wild guess (90% invalid): temporary for `n-(i+1)` did trigger the reservation, not materializing in code.

Comment: Well, maybe I guessed it correctly. If you introduce local temporary `long z = n-(i+1);` `B[i] = A[z];` , it will go into `-16(%rbp)`, other things stay as they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Compiler Explorer *(godbolt.org)*](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) is a great tool to look at generated assembly from various compilers and with different flags. Here's what `g++7 -O2` produces for your code:

```
mystery(long*, long*, long):
        test    rdx, rdx
        jle     .L1
        lea     rax, [rdi-8+rdx*8]
        sub     rdi, 8
.L3:
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rax]
        sub     rax, 8
        add     rsi, 8
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsi-8], rdx
        cmp     rax, rdi
        jne     .L3
.L1:
        rep ret
```

To answer your question: compiling with optimizations disabled usually unexpected/less sensible output. *"Why?"* is a difficult question to answer as this highly depends on how the compiler is implemented.

Here's a screenshot showing a comparison of `-O2`, `-O0` and `-Ofast`:

[image: comparison]

Try it out here: https://godbolt.org/g/pQ637a

Comment: Actually without optimisations, the generated code is very clear, because it mostly consists of pattern for construct of the original language. Optimised code is much less obvious for non-trivial programs. And don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: @Olaf: as OP's question shows, the generated code with `-O0` is not very clear - in this case the code generated with `-O2` more closely resembles the original one. Also, I will post and and encourage posting screenshots where appropriate - in this case the coloring and alignment of the columns is way superior to text.